# Does the C language impose global linking?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, linker, standards

If we have a set of modules (translation units)
symbols can be linked in two manners:

1. 'local' linking - given exported symbol 'a'
   can be linked to the appropriate module m1 and other given 
   symbol 'a' from different module can be linked to other
   appropriate module m2. With this manner of linking there 
   will be no collision even if two modules use the same 
   symbol name - they just must not be linked to the same 
   module
2. 'global' linking - all symbol names are thrown 
   in one bag at link time. It makes symbol space pollution
   and it is not necessary (I consider it a 'design bug' 
   in c linking system )

C language probably do not imposes 'global' linking,
but linkers do AFAIK

Hope the question is appropriate. It is about c-language 
and it is clear, "*Does the C language impose the global way of linking 
or not?*"

//edit

It was said below that C99 imposes that. TNX for answer.

Do the first c standard imposed that too? Im very curious 
about oryginal c creators intentions here. (As I said 
I consider global linking as a bad choice in c language)

Comment: Euh, C doesn't really have namespaces, only scopes, but apart from that in the majority of the cases, 1 identifier == 1 symbol

Comment: C was deliberately designed to impose no extra semantics on a linker beyond Fortran's requirements.

Answer (score 5):

From C99 §6.2.2 *Linkage of identifiers*

> In the set of translation units and libraries that constitutes an entire program, each
>   declaration of a particular identifier with *external linkage* **denotes the same object or
>   function**. Within one translation unit, each declaration of an identifier with *internal
>   linkage* denotes the same object or function. Each declaration of an identifier with no
>   linkage denotes a unique entity.

You're talking about symbols with external linkage, so no, you can't have more than one of such a thing in an entire program.

As for your proposed "local linking", how would the compiler or linker know which symbol to bind with if there are multiple things with exactly the same name?

Comment: The cite above is about one module, it do not states that you cannot have the same symbol name in other module. As to how would he know - by command line for example you could use it "link m1 a, m2 b"  instead of "link m1 m2 a b " if a and b have cooliding symbol local linkage will do that global will fail

Comment: The quote above is for an "entire program" for the external linkage case, not one translation unit (what I think you're referring to with the term "module"). You can have multiple symbols with the same name with _internal linkage_, but those are only visible within one translation unit. There is no "local linkage" in C that would match what you're describing.

Answer (score 1):

Identifiers in C have one of three types of *linkage* associated:

1. **internal**, when declared with `static`. Can only be referenced in the same translation unit.
2. **external**, when declared with `extern` (which is also the default). Can be referenced in any of the translation units comprising a program
3. **none**, when they are no part of linking (macros, automatic variables, type names, ..)

That's it. Does that in some way not do what you refer to?

Comment: This is releted. But it is not clear if this is all. If this is all global linking wouldnt be imposed.

Comment: Right. Your definition of *global linking* <-> *all symbol names are thrown in one bag at link time* does not exist in the linkage model of the C language specification.

Comment: So linkage is out of scope of c language? What defines it, its undefined?

Comment: No. The linkage in C is as I have described. But none of the three matches what you wrote, so there's no *global linking as defined by grunge fightr*.

Answer (score 0):

The C standard does not say anything about modules/dynamic libraries. These are covered by other standards, e.g: ELF. So, as long as you are using multiple modules/dynamic libraries, you are outside the territory of ISO C. C compilers for tiny embedded systems should't be required to care about modules.

Comment: So linking is just no subject of C?

Comment: @grungefightr: _dynamic_ linking is no subject of C.